# Symfony 3 - Ckeditor bundle : Unrecognized options "template, template_parameters"

Tags: symfony, templates, ckeditor

I am using Symfony 3 with the [Ivory Bundle Ckeditor](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryCKEditorBundle) 4.0.5

I am Using template HTML, [here the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/IvoryCKEditorBundle/usage/template.html), but I have an issue when I want to use external template (the latest example).

When I use `html: 'myhtml'`, it is ok but when I use :

```
template:     'AppBundle:Ckeditor:h2_page.html.twig'
template_parameters:
    type: 'general'
```

It doesn't work, because I have an error :

> Unrecognized options "template, template_parameters" under "ivory_ck_editor.templates.templates_perso.templates.0"

I don't understand why It looks wrong whereas the documention write you can use it.

Comment: Can you show you entire configuration for `ivory_ck_editor`?

Comment: It was a bug with the 4.0.5 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I didn't notice there was a version 4.0.6, I did the update and it is working now !

Sorry !

Comment: Or you can just delete this question :)